Does German have the same poetic use of singular nouns as English?
I have a piece of text to translate with lines of dialogue using singular nouns like the following:

Is it not filled with danger, having varg and troll lurk behind every tree?


It is welcoming to creatures of all the worlds, from troll to human ...

The normal colloquial way of saying the second line would be "... from trolls to humans," but these characters are rather theatrical so it makes sense for them to be speaking in a different register. I am not sure if using the singular this way makes sense in German, though. Can I say "von Troll bis Mensch" instead of "von den Trollen bis zu den Menschen," and does that convey the same impression of their speaking style?

I think the test for this kind of higher/old-timey register is "How would Tolkien write it?" I'm not sure your best bet is to translate this on a word by word or even sentence by sentence basis. In German you'd ihrzen a lot, and there's no English equivalent unless you go full Shakespearean and use thee's and thou's. And, for example, when Gandalf says "Fly, you fools!", the "fly" is high register, but in the German "Flieht, ihr Narren!" it's "Narren" that's high register. "The Witcher" series in German might be a good model for this, since ihrzen is pretty much the default there.

That works and is good German. The most idiomatic and theatrical  way is to use Dativ singular:

... vom Troll bis zum Mensch(en).

I prefer herein the slightly dated Dativ form with ending en. You could use plural, but it sounds a little bit less elegant:

... von Trollen bis zu Menschen.

